# Booleans: Functions that get same results using != and ==

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, bioinformatics

I am experimenting with using different booleans to get the same results. I have two functions and I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

This works:

```
dna='ATGTGGTAG'

def orf_4(dna):
    if dna[len(dna)-3:]=='TGA' or dna[len(dna)-3:]== 'TAG' or dna[len(dna)-3:]=='TAA':
        return 'This could be an ORF'
    else:
        return 'This is not an ORF'

print orf_4(dna)
```

This does not. It returns 'This is not an ORF' for any input.

```
dna='ATGTGGTAG'

def orf_3(dna):
    if dna[len(dna)-3:]!='TGA' or dna[len(dna)-3:]!= 'TAG' or dna[len(dna)-3:]!='TAA':
        return 'This is not an ORF'
    else:
        return 'This could be an ORF' 
print orf_3(dna)
```

Does anybody have a suggestion as to why this is?

Comment: Try changing `or` to `and`, which is what I'm thinking you want.

Comment: You need to replace `or`s with `and`s

Comment: Look up [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Man, that was simple....

Comment: `dna[len(dna)-3:]` can be written as just `dna[-3:]`

Answer (score 2):

Your `or` between each conditional should actually be an `and`

Comment: This only answers part of the question... you might explain why.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is because when you reverse logical equivalence of  ```condition_1 or condition_2``` it should be ```not condition_1 and not condition_2```

ref: De Morgan's law

Answer (score 1):

with your first and second if statement, the return block will execute if any of the conditions return `True`.

eg

```
>>> True or True or False
True
>>>
>>> True or False or False
True
```

So in the second example `dna[len(dna)-3:]` cannot be equal to all three strings, so at least two of the conditions are going to return `True`, meaning the if statement will return `True`.

For the second statement, you should use `and` instead of `or`. If one condition returns `False` the whole statement will return `False`.

eg

```
>>> True and False and True
False
```